# how to use StreamBuilder for navigation from one page to another page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to check if the user's phone number is present in firestre or not? if it is present in firestore then it will Navigate to the MyHomePage(). It is not Navigate to MyHomePage

My code is

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _firestore.collection('users').snapshots(),
                     builder: (context, snapshot){
                            if(!snapshot.hasData){
                              return Text('Please Enter data');
                            }
                            final ph=snapshot.data.documents;
                            List<String> store=[];
                            for(var phonenum in ph){
                                  final catA=phonenum.data['Phone'];
                                  store=[catA];
                                  for(int i=0;i>=store.length;i++){
                                    if(_phone==store[i]){
                                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyHomePage.id);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                      Text('Phone is not registered yet');
                                    }

                                  }

                                };?
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49768314/8791788)

Comment: The page is not Navigate to MyHomePage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Querysnapshot, you can use `DocumentSnapshot`. It suits well for your situation.

an overview of code:

```
Future checkIfAvailableOrNot() async{
DocumentSnapshot doc = await db.collection('users').document(_phone).get();
if(doc.exists)
{
   //navigate to other page
}
else{
   print('no user found');
}
}
```